# Communicate to BLE Peripheral incase the iOS app is not running on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I have been researching since last 2 days. I have an iOS app and watch kit extension. In iOS app I have included `CBCentralManager` and connected to Peripheral. Everything is working fine incase if the iOS app running parallel to the apple watchkit app. Even though my iOS app not running I want to communicate to BLE Peripheral device. Is it possible ??. Please let me know. Any ideas/suggestions could be very helpful. Thank you for spending your valuable time.

Comment: Have you read the section on background operation in the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide?

Comment: Yes but I didn't find any relevant information

Comment: There is a whole section on background operation. If you are wanting to connect to the peripheral from the watch without the iOS device then this is not possible